# StackOverflow exception at the end of a webservice (No recursion / infinite loop) [ASP.NET App]

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

First of all, I would like to apologize if my language is not the best, I'm acutally not english.

To begin with, I work in a company and I'm maintaining an **ASP.NET MVC 3.0** application. Recently the client which I'm working for, submitted a report telling that when he validate a certain page (I will describe how it works later), the app was saving the values but returned an error page.

After a few research, I found out that the application was getting a **StackOverflow Exception** at the end of **the webservice's call**. This exception is occuring in **mscorlib.dll**.

The problem doesn't happen everytime, it only happens when there is a lot of products related to the one validated in the page.

I tried to use **WinDbg** to get more information about the **StackOverflow Exception** but it didn't really helped me...  [The first warning I caught was this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPvZN.png)

If you have any questions or informations, feel free to tell me.

**EDIT :**

I have no exception details, no stacktrace etc. The only thing I have is the picture I mentioned earlier.

**Emplacement of the call stack :**

mscorlib.dll!System.Text.StringBuilder.appendFormatHelper(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, System.Paramsarray args) + 0x363 bytes

**About the code :**

I'm calling the webservice through the following code,

```
 var retour = WServiceEtape.SavePassageSaisiePere(
            new DtoSaisiePassagePere
            {
                PassagePrincipal = _passagePrincipal,
                IsUpdateFils = passageDejaExistant,
                PassagePere = _passageAssocie,
                IsUpdatePere = passageAssocieDejaExistant,
                PiecesJointesToSave = piecesJointesToSave.ToList(),
                PiecesJointesToDelete = piecesJointesToDelete.ToList(),
                LitigesToSave = litigesToSave.ToList(),
                RelancesToDelete = relancesToDelete.ToList(),
                DecalageHoraire = decalageHoraire,
                ModeSaisie = GetModeSaisie(),
                IdPassagePrecedent = identifiantPassagePrecedent
            });
```

Here is the webservice's method :

```
public PassagePere SavePassageSaisiePere(DTO.DtoSaisiePassagePere parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            IEtapeManagementService service = IoCFactory.Instance.CurrentContainer.Resolve<IEtapeManagementService>();
            return service.SavePassageSaisiePere(
                parameters.PassagePrincipal,
                parameters.IsUpdateFils,
                parameters.PassagePere,
                parameters.IsUpdatePere,
                parameters.PiecesJointesToSave,
                parameters.PiecesJointesToDelete,
                parameters.LitigesToSave,
                parameters.RelancesToDelete,
                parameters.DecalageHoraire,
                parameters.ModeSaisie);
        }
        catch (ExceptionsDefinitions.IncompleteTransactionException ex)
        {
            //log exception for manage health system
            ILoggingManager traceManager = IoCFactory.Instance.CurrentContainer.Resolve<ILoggingManager>();
            traceManager.LoggingError(ex.Message);

            //propagate exception to client
            ServiceError detailedError = new ServiceError()
            {
                ErrorMessage = Resources.Messages.Exception_InvalidArguments
            };

            throw new FaultException<ServiceError>(detailedError);
        }
    }
```

Once I'm at the end of the previous method and run the the debuger in **Visual Studio**, the **StackOverflow Exception** occurs.

**SECOND EDIT :**

Here is the WinDbg's stack trace. As you can see there I cut some part cause there is a certain pattern that repeat in the first and second part of the picture, it also repeat a lot of time between those two parts that's why I didn't post it. The first part is the beginning, the second is before the end and the third is the end.

[WinDbg's stack trace picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9XUD.png)

Comment: No code, no exception details, no way to help.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace you had in WinDBG? First guess I'd say it sounds related to tracing....

Comment: Here it is, I just edit @tomasr . Btw, by tracing you mean logs ?

Comment: What is it that you're returning from your service? Sounds like a complex graph of objects with circular references (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx)... is that right?

Comment: I'm actually returning an object which define a product's transit. This object is composed with all children's transit, parent's transit, attachments etc .. But there is no circular references in those parts of code...

Comment: But you have stuff with IsReference=True in the contracts, right?